# undefined method `authenticate_user! Api::PostsController in Devise / Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

There is the following routes in my project:

```
  root 'home#index'

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "api/sessions" }
    resources :posts
  end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts,        dependent: :destroy
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

    validates :name, presence: true

    devise :database_authenticatable, :rememberable
end
```

Session controller:

```
class Api::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    @user = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:user][:email])
    if @user && @user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
        sign_in(@user)
    else
        warden.custom_failure!
      @errors = [ 'Invalid email or password' ]
        render 'api/shared/errors', status: :unauthorized
    end
    end
end
```

Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  #protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

At last my Post controller:

```
class Api::PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [ :create ]

    def create
      current_user.posts.create!(post_params)
    end

    private

        def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
        end
end
```

But when I try to create a new Post I get the following error: "undefined method `authenticate_user! Api::PostsController". If I delete it, I get the error about 'current_user' method. What's the trouble? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 12):

You get that error because of nesting devise within the `:api` namespace in your `routes.rb` file. Therefore, you should authenticate users in the following way:

```
class Api::PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_api_user!, only: [ :create ]
end
```

Comment: This is a very weird pattern!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem using devise.
The issue was that i named my db with a different name rather than user ( i named xuser).
In my case all i had to do was rename the vars in my controller.
Something like this

```
before_action :authenticate_xuser!, only: [ :create ]

def create
    current_xuser.posts.create!(post_params)
end

private

def post_params
       params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
end
```

Hope it helps!