# Devise methods undefined in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 app with the Devise gem installed. My project is set up in such a way, that all controllers are namespaced...Even Devise controllers.

In my routes file I have done this(This will better explain my namespacing structure):

```
controllers: {
    sessions: "api/v1/public/members/users/sessions",
    passwords: "api/v1/public/members/users/passwords",
    registrations: "api/v1/public/members/users/registrations",
},
path_names: { 
  sign_in: 'login', 
  password: 'forgot', 
  sign_up: 'register',
  sign_out: 'signout'
}
```

I have also setup the devise view files to reflect the required namespaced structure.

I have included the following in my ApplicationController.rb:

```
before_action :authenticate_api_v1_public_members_user!
```

Since my Devise controllers are namespaced, the standard 'before_action :authenticate_user!' method needed to be updated to the one above in order to work.

The issue that I'm experiencing, is that none of the Devise helper methods are available in any of my views. When calling 'current_user' or 'user_signed_in?' in a view, I am presented with an 'undefined method' error when refreshing my browser. I tried namespacing these helper methods as well, but to no avail.

**UPDATE**
Models are not namespaced in my app. I am using a normal User model. Only controllers are namespaced and are structured as indicated by the route above.

Does anybody have experience with a similar issue?

Comment: :authenticate_api_v1_public_members_user!     It looks very weird!  This Devise helper should have nothing to do with your namespaces. The name of the method depends of the name of your user model. From your example I may gess that your user model is ApiV1PublicMemberUser

Comment: I got the tip for a namespaced authenticate method here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29409283/1933068 . I have also updated my question to explain the Model @chumakoff

Comment: If it really works this way, you must use methods `current_api_v1_public_members_user!` and `api_v1_public_members_user_signed_in?` instead of `current_user!` and `user_signed_in?`

Comment: Wow your suggestion actually worked. I did something similar before, but my word sequence was incorrect. Can you please add this as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted. Thanks @chumakoff

Comment: I am very surprised that it works like this. Got something new to know. Thank you! I created an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be that Devise is nested within the `:api_v1_public_members` namespace in your routes.rb. In this case it affects not only on `authenticate_user!` method, changing it into `authenticate_api_v1_public_members_user!`, but on the others methods too.

- `current_user` turns to `current_api_v1_public_members_user`
- `user_signed_in?` turns to `api_v1_public_members_user_signed_in?`

There is similar problem here [undefined method `authenticate_user! Api::PostsController in Devise / Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164906/undefined-method-authenticate-user-apipostscontroller-in-devise-rails-4/29409283#29409283)