# Authenticated and unauthenticated routes for Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have created an application in using Rails 5. My user auth, is managed by the Devise gem.

I need to have different root paths for authenticated and unauthenticated users. I followed the tips given [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Define-a-different-root-route-for-logged-in-out-users). Everything seems really straight forward, but after signing in, I am still redirected to the normal root_path when clicking on my 'Home' link for example.

Here is my route.rb code:

```
authenticated :user do
  root to: 'api/v1/private/reporting/dashboards/summaries#index', as: :authenticated_root
end
root to: 'landing#index', as: :root
```

Here is the code for the 'Home' link in my navbar:

```
- if api_v1_public_members_user_signed_in?
  = link_to 'Home', authenticated_root_path
- else 
  = link_to 'Home', root_path
```

Can anybody spot something that I might be missing?

** FYI the 'api_v1_public_members_user_signed_in?' method might look unfamiliar but it's required since I'm namespacing my devise controllers. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752913/devise-methods-undefined-in-rails-project?noredirect=1#comment64881290_38752913) for more information on this.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping both your authenticated and unauthenticated root paths under `devise_scope` and giving them both separate names:

```
devise_scope :user do
  authenticated :user do
    root to: 'api/v1/private/reporting/dashboards/summaries#index', as: :authenticated_root
  end

  unauthenticated :user do
    root to: 'landing#index', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
end
```

Then, change your view to:

```
- if api_v1_public_members_user_signed_in?
  = link_to 'Home', authenticated_root_path
- else 
  = link_to 'Home', unauthenticated_root_path
```

Comment: Also does not seem to work as expected. I'm still being redirected to the 'unauthenticated_root_path' @PaulFioravanti

Answer (score 2):

The [devise docs](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Define-a-different-root-route-for-logged-out-users) provide a pattern for this.

###### Context

- Rails 7
- Devise 4.8.1

In `routes.rb`:

```rb
  unauthenticated do
    root "user#index"
  end

  authenticated :wealth_manager do
    root "user#secret", as: :authenticated_root
  end
```